# I have tried to excel export with the format of xls using PHP. but it didn't support Burmese language

Tags: php, excel, export

Please find the sample code

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen(content));
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream, charset=UTF-8; encoding=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".xls");
echo $xls_output;
exit;``
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think excel will treat your stream as utf-8 if a bom is found at the begining of the stream. Try to start your output stream with UTF-8 BOM after headers like this :

```
echo pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf);
echo $xls_output;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **encoding to Unicode** and maybe **charset to UTF-16**:

The following link will guide you to proper settings depending on the language:
http://www.unicode.org/faq/myanmar.html

You must also have the font installed on your machine.